# cached data base

Tags: java, database, caching

in my project i need a tow tables each of it has about 2000 row , i want my application to be speed
so my db should load into memory (cached) when the app start and before it close the db have to be saved on the disk . i am using java and i want to use sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java, take a look at [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). It has in-memory databases, is written in Java and should provide the performance you need. Derby or HSQLDB are other Java alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) and [SqliteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)

Be aware though, that 2000rows is by no means large for a DB!

Comment: Yes, but unless you are constantly loading & writing the entire DB (let's assume 1k Bytes per record, thus DB < 5MB) it's not going to matter much, since the local disk-cache will do the work for your DB.

Comment: yes , but i dont make sure that my db dont get more records by time

Answer (score 1):

If the database that you need in memory is mostly read only I would keep a cache in memory but whenever there is a write I would propagate that change directly to the database.  This way if the application breaks down you have the current state already in the database.

This should be very simple to write using a Map (or a series of Maps if you need multiple keys to access the data).